# How to render flash flowplayer and html flowplayer in single web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer

I have a requirement wherein based on some condition I have to switch between flash and HTML flowplayer.

It is a single page app.

currently I am doing the following. But is there a better approach?

```
$.getScript("flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js", function(){
    $.getScript("flowplayer/jdataview.js", function(){
        $.getScript("flowplayer/easybits-helper.js", function(){
            $.getScript("flowplayer/easybits-mp4.js", function(){
                $.getScript("flowplayer/easybits-multistreaming.js", function(){
                    $.getScript("flowplayer/easybits-flowplayer-flash-scrubber-preview.js", function(){
                        $.fn.flashFlowplayer = $.fn.flowplayer;
                        $.fn.flowplayer = undefined;
                        window.flashFlowplayer = flowplayer;
                        flowplayer = undefined;
                        $.getScript("flowplayer/flowplayerhtml5/flowplayer.min.js", function() {
                            $.fn.htmlFlowplayer = $.fn.flowplayer;
                            window.htmlFlowplayer = flowplayer;
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});

/* and to render a flash video I use */

flashFlowplayer(sourceElement[0].id, {
    src: "flowplayer/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.16.swf",
    wmode: 'opaque'
}, oFlowPlayerConfig);

/* to render htmlFlowplayer I use */
$el.htmlFlowplayer({ 
    "ratio": oParam.ratio, 
    "embed": false, 
    "playlist":[[{ "mp4":  sVideoUrl }]],
});
```

Comment: show you've made some effort.

Comment: @doveyg I have updated my question with sample code which I am currently using.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the scripts by using `<script>` elements instead of this deeply nested mess of `$.getScript`. The browser might download them in any order but it will *execute* the contents in order. That means the browser might request `easybits-helper.js` already while it's executing the content of `flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js`.

This code is equivalent to the above:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer/jdataview.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer/easybits-helper.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer/easybits-mp4.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer/easybits-multistreaming.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer/easybits-flowplayer-flash-scrubber-preview.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.flashFlowplayer = $.fn.flowplayer;
    $.fn.flowplayer = undefined;
    window.flashFlowplayer = flowplayer;
    flowplayer = undefined;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer/flowplayerhtml5/flowplayer.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.htmlFlowplayer = $.fn.flowplayer;
    window.htmlFlowplayer = flowplayer;
</script>
```

but it allows the client to cache the scripts properly and load them in parallel. It's also much more readable.